# facebook og:image on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

This is really strange and makes me sleepless

The source code is written out like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.aveny.se/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/jafar_utvald-150x150.jpg" />
```

(the image exists, did check!)
But a totally different image is posted on facebook.

The SDK is written directly after the `<body>` tag.

I have the right fb-like code.

Comment: To check a post http://www.aveny.se/?reportage=varldens-top-5-bistros-2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the facebook graph api.
The first you should know is when somebody shared your link, facebook will crawl your site for the og:image tag. If it doesn't find them, will select an image found on your site. After the first share, facebook will save that images, so if you added the code after the fisrt share, it's useless. You can try it with another post. The second issue is to add

```
<link href="http://www.aveny.se/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/jafar_utvald-150x150.jpg" rel="image_src"/>
```

to your source code. This solved my problem. I hope you can solve it too!